# CSS: My site looks exactly the same in Firefox/Chrome/Safari - but IE7, it's all out of whack

Tags: css, internet-explorer

On [my site][1] everything looks great in Firefox/Chrome/Safari (all the same) - but IE7, it's all out of whack.

Any ideas how I can modify my CSS to make IE7 at least somewhat usable?

Comment: just a tip... validate your html, you have 389 Errors, 183 warning(s) ... http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uptownelite.com%2F%3Fcity%3DDallas%2CTX

Comment: yeah... a doctype and valid markup would help remove half of browser compatibility problems..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing the same issues in IE 7 and 8.

If I change to standards mode instead of [quirks more](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html), I have no issue.  I think if you add a doctype, problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that [this project](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) at Google Code will often clean up major problems with IE(6/7). The relevant parts follow:

Use the following code to get all IE to act like IE9:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Use the following code to get all IE to act like IE8:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

---

Also, as superUntitled pointed out, it would be a good idea to make sure your code is syntactically valid. Your code seems to be a mix of HTML and XHTML, so I've attached the various validation checks to help you to choose one:

[HTML 4.01 Strict: 46 Errors, 30 Warnings](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uptownelite.com%2F%3Fcity%3DDallas%2CTX&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=HTML+4.01+Strict&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.767)
[XHTML 1.0 Strict: 398 Errors, 183 Warnings](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uptownelite.com%2F%3Fcity%3DDallas%2CTX&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=XHTML+1.0+Strict&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.767)

It seems like you started out with XHTML, as evidenced by your link to a XHTML DTD, but your markup is closer to the HTML standard. Finally, note that a simple fix can often clear up several errors, so don't try to fix multiple things at once. Fix, update, then re-check the validator.

A quick glance shows that you've haven't closed your `</html>` tag. That's probably a few of the errors right there.